# Insert a password into the terminal through a script?

Tags: command-line, password

I was wondering if there was a way to insert a password when it's asked for in the terminal while using a script.  I would prefer to not have to type it but I suppose that's not the worst thing that could happen.

Comment: [This expect question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4780893/9224859) might help you.

Comment: This also depends a bit on the commands you want to run in the script. If you want no password at all for a certain script have a look at [visudo](https://askubuntu.com/a/192062/423684)

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this in your script:

```
echo 'yourPassword' | sudo -S yourCommand
```

The `-S` flag makes `sudo` read the password from the standard input. You can check it in manual pages using `man sudo`:

> -S, --stdin
>
> Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the
>   standard input instead of using the terminal device. The password must
>   be followed by a newline character.

If you get an error using this, it's because your sudo access token is active, to get around that, you could use `-k` to reset the access token:

```
echo 'yourPassword' | sudo -kS yourCommand
```

Hope it helps.