# User in sudo group, but still being asked for password

Tags: sudo

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my home server. I have just one user which I want to be able to use `sudo`, but I can't get it to work. I already ran `sudo usermod -aG sudo rlommers`.
the output of `id rlommers` also states that I'm in the sudo group.
However, when I run `sudo apt-get update`, I'm still required to enter the password. Why is that?

```
rlommers@server [~]$ id rlommers
uid=1000(rlommers) gid=1000(rlommers) groups=1000(rlommers),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lxd),117(docker)
rlommers@server [~]$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for rlommers:
```

**EDIT**
Sorry! For future reference: I already solved it by adding `rlommers ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to the sudo file.

Comment: It may be helpful to others searching for a solution to this issue if you were to add your solution as an answer to this question, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a user to the `sudo` group simply allows them to run commands as an elevated user - much the same as `doas`. As in [this great answer for **AWS**](https://askubuntu.com/a/192062/212930) the solution here is:

```
   $User ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

(Where $User is your User ID)

....and a complementary, be careful with no prompt in an elevated environment!