# How to give passwordless sudo through automated script

Tags: 20.04, sudo, visudo

Anyone who has used Multipass or AWS is familiar with the `ubuntu` user who has passwordless sudo access. I am launching multiple virtual machines via `multipass` each with many users and I want passwordless sudo for their accounts for two reasons

1. They can only login with their public/private and not a username/password so they can't type in a password for `sudo` if they don't have one
2. Developers need to be able to call `sudo apt-get`

I am aware that I can issue the command `sudo visudo` and [make some changes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password) to provide passwordless sudo, however, this requires human interaction. I tried hacking this with sed (`sudo sed -i "s/%admin\s*ALL=(ALL)\s*ALL/%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL/g" /etc/sudoers`) but something breaks and then I can't get into `/etc/sudoers`, not even with the `ubuntu` user.

Finally, I tried looking at the groups that `ubuntu` is a member of and noticed that it is a member of `adm` which I assume is admin, and I [blindly] added all the user accounts to that group but that did not work either.

I have two questions, which are really the same question

1. How is it that Ubuntu can call sudo without a password and where is this specified?
2. How can I extend this same privilege to other users but in an automated fashion?

Comment: Your `cat | sed | tee` combination is usesless use of `cat` and `sed`. You can simply use `sed -i '...' /etc/sudoers`.

Comment: @pLumo thanks, I updated the command. I still don't get the intended results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multipass supports cloud-init and with it you can do all those things automatically without any script.

`multipass launch --cloud-init <file> ...`

And in cloudinit file you can specify all users to be created and you can give them passwordless sudo.

It would look like this

```
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
packages:
  - ...
users:
  - name: ubuntu
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    home: /home/ubuntu
    shell: /bin/bash
    groups: [adm, audio, cdrom, dialout, floppy, video, plugdev, dip, netdev, libvirtd]
    lock_passwd: True
    gecos: Ubuntu
```

Have a look at cloudinit [documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for details.

[Edit - adding tested example]

```
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
packages:
users:
  - name: user1
    shell: /bin/bash
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa ...
  - name: user2
    shell: /bin/bash
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa ...
```

```
$ multipass launch --cloud-init cloudinit.yaml 
Launched: great-dalmatian
```

```
$ ssh user1@10.88.17.191
...
user1@great-dalmatian:~$ id
uid=1000(user1) gid=1000(user1) groups=1000(user1)
user1@great-dalmatian:~$ sudo id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

```
$ ssh user2@10.88.17.191 "id; sudo id"
uid=1001(user2) gid=1001(user2) groups=1001(user2)
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought CloudInit was some cloud service like AWS