# SSH repository apt get update without password

Tags: apt, updates, ssh, repository

I'm trying to build a private apt repository using reprepro. I managed to get password-less SSH login after creating a SSH key chain. I can successful login to the repository if I SSH into it.

On the client machine I added the repository in the apt sources list like:

```
deb ssh://repo@192.168.60.128:/home/repo/repos/apt/ubuntu xenial main
```

But when I try to use `apt-get update`, I still need to enter the password otherwise it won't proceed. It only shows:

```
100% [Connecting to repo@192.168.60.128]
```

Is there a way that apt can use my key get access to the repository without entering a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a ssh key as root on the client machine. After that i needed to add this public key to the authorized_keys on the ubuntu server machine. Now I can make use of the apt repository using ssh with the keys without entering a password.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the command to /etc/sudoers. Have a look at this [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password)

Another option is to ssh passwordless with the root user but, it's generally considered a very bad idea. 
[How to setup passwordless SSH access for root user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115151/how-to-setup-passwordless-ssh-access-for-root-user)

In your repo, become root with `sudo su` and then run this command:

`echo "%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get" >> /etc/sudoers`

This will allow any user to run apt-get without password. This command is used to upgrade, but it can also be used to install/uninstall packages... be careful. I think it would be better to use the password or enable automatic updates in the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I still can't update without entering the password of the ssh repo. I tried this:

sudo visudo
guy guy-rcs=(root)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt-get update,/usr/bin/apt-get upgrade

Comment: Undo your changes and check my edit and see if it helps. You don't need to specify update and upgrade at the end, the apt-get command will run passwordless with any argument.

Comment: Tried your new command on the client side and on the server side. I can't run apt-get without sudo. I hope you can help me.

Comment: You should be able to run apt-get with sudo but without a password. It worked for me. Check all the steps carefully and I hope you can solve it.

Comment: Tried it out this is when I try to apt-get update after your instructions 
'guy@guy-rcs:~$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
'

Comment: you have to put `guy@guy-rcs:~$ sudo apt-get update` and if you've done the rest, it won't ask for a password.