# Permission denied please try again ssh error

Tags: server, ssh, users

I had a root access to my server and I was logged in through ssh. I I did this in my

```
AllowUsers john
```

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

in this file.

Now after this I rebooted the server. now I am unable to login through root user and unable to login through john as well. nothing is working. Please help?

my root user was this e.g `root@ip`

If I try to login `ssh root@ip` through root it says this

**Permission denied, please try again.**

If I try to login with john it says

**Shell access is not enabled on your account!
If you need shell access please contact support.**

I don't understand why I am unable to login through my root account.

Note: I can successfully login through in WHM

Comment: can you post the exact command and (error) output of the terminal when you are trying to log in as john?

Comment: @ Sebastian Stark if I try to login through john it says Shell access is not enabled on your account!
If you need shell access please contact support.

Comment: @SebastianStark I have updated my question

Answer (score 2):

By default, logging in as root using password is disabled. You should change the `PermitRootLogin` setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` accordingly to allow that, if it is what you want. Alternatively set up public key authentication for the root account. See e. g. [How to set up passwordless SSH access for root user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115151/how-to-set-up-passwordless-ssh-access-for-root-user) for an example. Unfortunately this will be impossible to do without help from your hoster if you really locked yourself out and logging in as *john* also does not work.

In addition to this, if you do not add *root* to the `AllowUser` directive as well, the setting of PermitRootLogin will have no effect anyway.

So to fix your particular problem make those two settings in `sshd_config` look like this:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
AllowUsers root john
```

and then restart sshd or reboot the server. Afterwards you should be able to log in as root using a password.

As for the error message when you are trying to log in as *john*: This does not look like a normal ssh or Ubuntu error message but rather something your hoster added. You should probably do what it says and contact support.

### Safety measures

In general, if you are messing with sshd settings there is an easy way to test things: Simply restart the sshd service using `service ssh restart` and try things out from another terminal. Do not terminate your existing session. If something goes wrong you still have the running session and can revert the wrong settings.

Rebooting the whole server is never necessary for activating changes to sshd.

Comment: I have the access of whm. Can I edit the ssd file from there

Comment: Answer updated, you should be able to recover using those instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Also note: the **AllowUsers** specifies that login is allowed only for those user names that match a pattern listed with this keyword. By default, login is allowed for all user names.  So, with your configuration, **john** is the only user that can log in using ssh.

The answer from Sebastian Stark is also correct: root would not be able to login by default, even if you had included root in **AllowUsers**.

So: I recommend, first, making sure that user **john** can login correctly.  Make sure that **john** has a shell assigned in `/etc/passwd` and give him one using `chsh` if necessary.  Then, login as **john** and use sudo if you need root access.

Comment: In my case, the user was pointed to a wrong bash **"/bin/sh"** instead of **"/bin/bash"** and I can't log in correctly and the error was **"Permission denied, please try again."**. Fixing to the correct bash restored my login again because I tried the other answers without success so thank you @Martin-v