# How to access Ubuntu using Root

Tags: lubuntu

I have just created a root account on my ubuntu1 server, see below:

```
packt@ubuntu1:~$ 
packt@ubuntu1:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for packt: 
root@ubuntu1:~#
```

When I try to ssh this ubuntu server from my centos machine (or any machine for that matter) using the following I get permission denied.

```
[packt@centos1 ~]$ ssh root@ubuntu1
root@ubuntu1's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@ubuntu1's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@ubuntu1's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
[packt@centos1 ~]$
```

I know I can su into the root from the ubuntu1 machine but I need to access the machine using root from other machines.

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using sudo to get a root shell. This does not mean that you have enabled the root account.

To enable root login, you have to set a password for root:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Then you have to edit your `sshd_config`

```
 sudo editor /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Change

```
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
```

to

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Exit the editor, and restart sshd with

sudo systemctl restart openssh-server

Note that this is not recommended. I can't really think of any reasons why you **need** root access via ssh. Commands can be prepended with sudo, and sudo configured for passwordless use. File copies? You can usually modify the permissions of the destination, so that you don't have to be root.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple causes here.

First, many Linux distributions come, or at least suggest that you lock out the `root` user from `ssh`.  This is because every system comes with `root`, and it makes it easier to brute-force a machine if you're aware of a user.  Not a foolproof, but helpful.

Otherwise, you need to understand that each user has their own password, and it is the password of that user, and the entries found for `sudo` in `/etc/sudoers`, that allow a user to successfully execute a command with `sudo`.

To clarify, when you use this command, you are using the USER password:

```
sudo su -i
```

`sudo` checks if you're allowed to run the command, and also prompts you for your USER password.

When you log into a machine, you use that USER password again.  It is unlikely, and a bad practice, to have your USER and your root account share passwords.  In this case, since you know the USER password, you would do the following:

```
ssh USER@myserver
sudo su -
```

Here, you access the system using the USER account, and known password, and then escalate to root.  This solves either problem, and is how you should be escalating to root.

If you discover that your server allows root login, but you were using the password incorrectly, be sure to lock that down.  Other Answers to your question are suggesting you allow root login, but instead, I ask that you understand the situation, and stay secure by following this advice instead.  Look up `ssh` hardening, and at least set up `fail2ban`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, root access is disabled over ssh. You can enable root ssh access or ssh in as normal user and su or sudo.

**To enable root login via ssh:**

As root, edit the sshd_config file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config :

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
```

Add a line in the Authentication section of the file that says

> PermitRootLogin yes . ...

Save the updated /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
Restart the SSH server:

```
sudo service sshd restart.
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

This is not a good solution to the problem, because it exposes root, while the user has a proper user with sudo privileges already. This does not address the problem, but instead provides a workaround that needlessly increases risk and supports bad practice.

**Root login using SSH keys (possibly more secure):**

If you must root login over SSH it is quite possibly more secure (and easier) to login using SSH keys. The setup is a bit longer, but well outlined in [How to set up passwordless SSH access for root user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115151/how-to-set-up-passwordless-ssh-access-for-root-user)

Comment: thanks for getting in touch. I will try your suggestions. I just want to let you know what I'm actually trying to do. I'm trying to change the motd in /etc/motd with the account packt. However, that account isn't able to write to etc. Therefore, is there a command that I could use to allow the account packt the same permissions as root so that it can write to /etc ?

Comment: This is not a good solution to the problem, because it exposes `root`, while the user has a proper user with `sudo` privileges already.  This does not address the problem, but instead provides a workaround that needlessly increases risk and supports bad practice.

Comment: @earthmeLon I agree and have updated the answer with your info. thanks.

Comment: you can make it so your user doesn't need a password when sudoing, but I am not sure if this is any more secure.  perhaps root logon with ssh key would be better?

Comment: One idea is that it's more secure because an adversary has a lot harder time guessing `josh` over `root`, but you're right, you're at a security disadvantage by allowing escalation without a password, and these things start to add up.