# How do you install software and updates without a password in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, login, update-manager, password

Im looking for a way to remove the need of a password to install/uninstall and update software in Ubuntu 12.04?

Im trying to give some Windows users a smooth transition. They have Vista which doesnt require a password to install or update software.

Also without a password on the user account. How can i set it up to not automatically login  but also not require a password to login to the user?

thanks for any help!!

Comment: Your idea kind of defeats the purpose of using a more secure OS like Linux.  If you don't need security, keep your users on Windows.  
If you want to allow them access to install software, give them sudo rights like zubozrout explained.  If you don't want them to be hassled by the OS updates, then create a cron job to automatically do the updates for them.

Comment: @EdManet Requiring the user to enter a password to perform administrative tasks is one of a number of different security-related design decisions for default behavior. Many different factors contribute to security, and reconfiguring `sudo` to not prompt for a password does not render Ubuntu equivalent to Windows or any other operating system. It's not as simple as "need[ing] security" or not. Computer security is a multidimensional continuum, not an on-off switch.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer you are probably looking for:
[Run apt-get without sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74054/run-apt-get-without-sudo)

This way you have to set it for each program you want to use for installing things without specifically given root permission. e.g. for software-center it should look like this:

```
%usernameofaaffectedperson% ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/software-center
```