# How do I stop Ubuntu from asking for my password every time I install something?

Tags: prompt

Whenever I try to install a program I get a password authentication prompt asking me to punch in my password. I would like to know how to disable this.

I tried to google it and most of the stuff I find related to the login password, which isn't an issue for me as I disabled it at startup.

What I need to get rid of is the password prompt for installing and uninstalling stuff.

Comment: You really do not want to do this. This is the way Windows is and then opens system to potential for virus or hackers to access system. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RootSudo  and (but this has never worked for me): http://xkcd.com/149/

Comment: @oldfred Actually password-less sudo does not significantly weaken security. Once an attacker gains the ability to run programs as the unprivileged user, that attacker can install a key-logger to record the password at the next invocation of sudo and thereafter gain root privileges. You have to keep viruses/crackers out of the system entirely anyways, whether you use password-less sudo or not.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel Suggesting sudo isn't essential concerning security is false information.

Comment: @JacobVlijm It depends on the context. For a typical Ubuntu desktop user, it adds very little security to have a sudo password, in other contexts it may be more relevant.

Comment: These questions give better answers for modern GUI apps using polkit instead of sudo
https://askubuntu.com/q/98006/897087 https://askubuntu.com/q/3/897087

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo nano -w /etc/sudoers
```

(and enter your password one last time). Then use the editor to change the line that says:

```
%sudo  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

into:

```
%sudo  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

or even:

```
%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

(to allow assuming any group as well as any user).

Comment: So I changed it to "%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" and restarted. But when I opened the app store and tried to install an app... it still asked me for a password.

Comment: Type `groups` and check if your user is in the `sudo` group. If not, change `%sudo` into your user name and try again. If that doesn't work, then the prompt might not be related to `sudo` ...

Comment: Sudu is in groups. I tried to add my username, but the appstore still asks for a password.

Comment: Then I suspect the steps you took to disable the login password could've broken something.

Comment: Its possible, I'm an absolute novice. Heres a screenshot of my edits, does something look broken?

Comment: http://imgur.com/ZYm49qx

Comment: What happens when you do, e.g., `sudo ls` from the command line? Does it ask for a password?

Comment: It does not ask for a password.

Comment: Hmm, does the same happen using gksudo ls? (gksudo should just be sudo, but with a password dialog rather than a command prompt)

Comment: No requested password for gksudo ls either. It acts identically to sudo ls.

Comment: if you want to open the file with gedit `sudo gedit -w /etc/sudoers`

Comment: Editing `sudoers` also did not help me. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 12):

Type `sudo visudo` and this screen appears:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset, timestamp_timeout=120
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
```

The first command `Defaults env_reset, timestamp_timeout=120` has been modified with a timeout of 120 minutes between having to enter `sudo` password. The normal default is 5 minutes. Although you can change this to a very large number you will still have to enter it once per boot.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I wish I could disable it completely, but this is good too.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo nano -w /etc/sudoers
```

add `NOPASSWD` entry for your user:

```
yourusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

By default ubuntu logs you in as a non root user for the O/S safety.
It's there for a reason so that anybody who is new cannot mess up with the O/S itself accidently.
In case you don't want to be prompted for password there is another way

```
sudo su
```

now you are root. But be very careful in terms of anything you are doing.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't stop the ubuntu software store from still asking for a password when I try to install something.

Comment: Helpful tip, but doesn't directly answer the user's question.

Answer (score 0):

The password is required because it's using `sudo` to run the actual installation as root.

You may be able to address this by modifying:

```
/etc/sudoers
```

to allow it to run `apt-get` and `dpkg` without a password.

See:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers

[Run apt-get without sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74054/run-apt-get-without-sudo)).

Comment: editing the sudoers file seems to remove the password prompts for everything except the appstore. When I try to install something via appstore it still asks me for a password.

Answer (score 0):

Just type this command

```
echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: I realize that this is a duplicate answer, but it's worth saving because it's easier to understand than the original.