# Removed sudo Password Requirement in sudoers, Cannot Re-enable It

Tags: permissions, sudo, password, nano

I wanted to stop Ubuntu from requiring a password everytime I did nearly anything, so I followed instructions here to disable the password requirement in sudoers - [How do I stop Ubuntu from asking for my password every time I install something?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852527/how-do-i-stop-ubuntu-from-asking-for-my-password-every-time-i-install-something)

However, instead of providing universal superuser elevation, which is what I intended to accomplish, the password requirement was disabled but is still needed for nearly everything. I am simply not able to enter it anymore! Furthermore, Ubuntu no longer understands the "sudo" command and will not run any commands at an elevated level. I have no way of going back into the sudoers file and removing NOPASSWD because getting into the file requires elevation and I do not have permission to view it any longer.

How can this be reversed?

Comment: The virtual console produces the same errors as the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved -

I ran `pkexec visudo`, which allowed me to edit the sudoers file as superuser and remove the undesired line.